# Get stored procedures in packages in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

We call the following to get all stored procedures in oracle:

```
select object_name from user_procedures
```

And for each stored procedure, we call the following to get all parameters:

```
select object_name, argument_name, data_type, default_value, in_out, data_length, data_precision, data_scale, char_length from user_arguments order by POSITION
```

Which works great if the stored procedures are no in packages. But if they are in packages, then the first select will return the package name, not the stored procedure name, for each stored procedure.

For the case where the stored procedures are inside packages, what select can we call to get all of them? Preferably a call that returns all names for both inside packages and stand-alone.

Comment: Correction - USER_PROCEDURES does _not_ show "all stored procedures in oracle", as you assert.  It shows all procedures _owned by_ the user of the session in which the query is issued.

Answer (score 2):

But, they *are* exactly where you've been looking for ... `user_procedures`. It's just that object name isn't a *procedure*, but **package** name.

```
SQL> create package pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test;
  3    function f_test return number;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> select procedure_name
  2  from user_procedures
  3  where object_name = 'PKG_TEST';

PROCEDURE_NAME
------------------------------
F_TEST
P_TEST


SQL>
```

That's fine if procedures are exposed to public, i.e. they are named in package **specification**. If they are private to the package, then - I'm afraid - it isn't easy to find that info. Maybe by parsing the `USER_SOURCE`, searching for `procedure` string ...

P.S. As @Sayan commented, I was wrong about private procedures - there's the [PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/plscope.html#GUID-24109CB5-7BB9-48B2-AD7A-39458AA13C0C) which helps in that case.

Comment: We can use plsql_scope for private procedures/functions in package body: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/plscope.html#GUID-24109CB5-7BB9-48B2-AD7A-39458AA13C0C

Comment: Aha. Thank you, @Sayan.

Comment: Ok, two steps then. Get the package names and from each package get the stored procedure names. Which leads to the question, how do I know if what's returned from the first select is a package or a stored procedure? And in the second select, how can I get just stored procedures (no functions)? TIA